# How do I configure to use the Android SDK already installed on my system without downloading the Eclipse packages via "Install New Software"?

Tags: android, eclipse

While I was using Eclipse to develop my Java programs, I decided to do a little digging on Android. I learned that all I needed for Android development was the Android SDK, since I already have eclipse. The instructions were to open Eclipse and go to "Help" then to "Install new software". I realized that I would need to connect to the internet to do so.

Where I am, there is a terribly slow internet connection and trying to do that would be unrealistic since the download time is apparently 27 hours. However, I already [downloaded the Android SDK from this site](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html) when I was in the US.

Can I configure Eclipse to use this Android SDK without needing to download anything else from the "Install new software" screen? How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will still need to download an eclipse plugin so that Eclipse understands Android development. See [this page (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html), section "Troubleshooting ADT Installation", where it shows you how to do an offline installation. Make sure to check the prerequisites at the beginning of that page! After it's installed you can point it to the already-installed Android SDK.